# Scalar product on diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $D_n$ the space of $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with scalar product: $$(A,B)=\text{tr}(AB),$$
i want to prove that there exists unique $X\in D_n$ such that:
$$(X,A)=\text{tr}(A), \ \forall A\in D_n.$$
I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the identity matrix.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit The uniqueness is slightly less obvious, though. One needs to show the non-degeneracy of the scalar product.

Comment: @WhatsUp If i know that the scalar product is non-degeneracy or positive definite, what results i have to use for prove the existence ?